# My program keeps spamming print function Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Man, I'm on here a lot tonight.

Ok, so I just finished my assignment. My only problem at this point is when I go to test the "else", it keeps spamming print until I stop it.

Here is the full code.

```
import re
from statistics import mean


def file_info():

    # Open & read file
    grades_file = open('grades.txt', 'r')
    file_contents = grades_file.read()

    # Print Header & spacer
    print('Name' + '\t\tGrade')
    print('---------------------')

    # Print contents of file
    print(file_contents.rstrip('\n'))

    # Extract numbers from file, calculate avg
    num_list = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", file_contents)
    grades = [float(num) for num in num_list]
    average = mean(grades)

    # Print avg
    print('Average Grade:', format(average, '.2f'))

    # Close file
    grades_file.close()


def main():
    file_info()

    # Open file to append
    grades_file = open('grades.txt', 'a')

    # Continue program press y or n
    fwd = str(input('\nAdd another student (Y/N): '))

    while True:

        if fwd.lower() == 'y':
            while True:
                name = str(input("Enter student's name: "))

                if not name.isalpha():
                    print("Please enter a valid name.")
                    continue
                else:
                    break
            while True:
                grade = float(input("Enter student's grade: "))

                if grade < 0:
                    print("Input grade between 0-100.")
                    continue
                elif grade > 100:
                    print("Input grade between 0-100.")
                    continue
                else:
                    break

            # Write data to file
            grades_file.write(name + ' ' + str(grade) + '\n')

            # Continue adding more students?
            cont = str(input('Add another student (Y/N): '))

            if cont.lower() == 'y':
                continue

            elif cont.lower() == 'n':
                grades_file.close()
                file_info()
                exit()

            else:
                print('Choose "Y" or "N"')

        elif fwd.lower() == 'n':
            exit()

        else:
            print('Choose "Y" or "N"')
            continue


main()
```

If I try to test the last "else" statement, it spams "Choose Y or N" until I stop the program.

The only thing that stops it is if I "break" but then the program stops and doesn't try to ask the user input again. Ideas?

Edit:
This is what the output looks like

```
Choose "Y" or "N"
Choose "Y" or "N"
Choose "Y" or "N"
Choose "Y" or "N"
Choose "Y" or "N"
Choose "Y" or "N"
Choose "Y" or "N"
Choose "Y" or "N"
Choose "Y" or "N"
Choose "Y" or "N"
```

Comment: If you put it as an input statement, it will stay there until input is given

Comment: Maybe I should clarify, it's not asking the user for input constantly, It's printing the error message constantly.

Example: If I input an X instead of Y or N, it spams the error message nonstop.

Comment: is it the first or second else statement.

Comment: The very last one, right before main()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't ask new input from user.

```
        else:
            fwd=input('Choose "Y" or "N"')
            continue
```

should work.

--- EDIT ---

But I think that code is more complicated than neccessary. There is no reason to use `fwd` and `cont` variables, only one is needed. This should do as well:

```py
def main():
    file_info()

    # Open file to append
    grades_file = open('grades.txt', 'a')

    # Continue program press y or n


    while True:
        fwd = str(input('\nAdd another student (Y/N): '))
        if fwd.lower() == 'y':
            while True:
                name = str(input("Enter student's name: "))

                if not name.isalpha():
                    print("Please enter a valid name.")
                    continue
                else:
                    break
            while True:
                grade = float(input("Enter student's grade: "))

                if grade < 0:
                    print("Input grade between 0-100.")
                    continue
                elif grade > 100:
                    print("Input grade between 0-100.")
                    continue
                else:
                    break

            # Write data to file
            grades_file.write(name + ' ' + str(grade) + '\n')


        elif fwd.lower() == 'n':
            grades_file.close()
            file_info()
            exit() # Do we really want to exit here or just break the loop?

        else:
            print("Choose 'Y' or 'N')
```

Comment: How did I not realize that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you put this line:

```
fwd = str(input('\nAdd another student (Y/N): '))
```

inside the `While` loop, and remove the `continue` it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change fwd's value, because if it is not 'y' and you are inside that while True, it will not be able to avoid this very same else again.

Answer (score 1):

You only ask for the input once, so it only knows that value. What you need to do is put the input in the loop:

```
while True:
    fwd = str(input('\nAdd another student (Y/N): '))
    # code
```

This way each time, it loops, it is checking, otherwise